# Buckingham Pi theorem, repeating variables

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, mathematics, fluid

I'm having trouble understanding the 4th step to the Buckingham Pi theorem.

My variables are:

- weight ($\text{N}$) : $\text{MLT}^{-2}$
- h ($\text{m}$): $\text{L}$
- Diameter ($\text{m}$): $\text{L}$
- Orifice diameter ($\text{m}$): $\text{L}$
- flow rate Q ($\text{m}^3/\text{s}$) : $\text{L}^3\text{T}^{-1}$
- density ($\text{kg/m}^3$) : $\text{ML}^{-3}$
- fluid viscosity ($\text{Ns/m}^2$) : $\text{ML}^{-2}$

From this $k = 7$, $r = 3$, $\text{number of Pi groups} = 4$

I know the criteria for repeating variables, but I'm not 100% sure.

For instance, if i picked weight, height and flow rate will that have fulfilled all the criteria? I don't understand the dependent variable criteria.

Comment: Could you give a little more context about the problem you're trying to solve? You've given us some variables, but with no physical context, it obscures whatever relationships the variables might have between each other.